# Error while trying to fetch table from remote hive2 server using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to access tables from remote hive2 server from spark using the code below:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkConf, org.apache.spark.sql._
import com.typesafe.config._
import java.io._
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object stack {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
 val warehouseLocation = "/usr/hive/warehouse"
System.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL","jdbc:mysql://sparkserver:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true")
System.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName","hiveroot")
System.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword","hivepassword")
System.setProperty("hive.exec.scratchdir","/tmp/hive/${user.name}")
System.setProperty("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
   // System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://sparkserver:9083")
System.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
System.setProperty("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir","/user/hive/warehouse")


val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local")
.appName("spark remote")
   // .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL","jdbc:mysql://sparkserver:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true")
 .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL","jdbc:mysql://sparkserver:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName","hiveroot")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword","hivepassword")
  .config("hive.exec.scratchdir","/tmp/hive/${user.name}")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
//  .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://sparkserver:9083")  
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  .config("hive.querylog.location","/tmp/hivequerylogs/${user.name}")
  .config("hive.support.concurrency","false")
  .config("hive.server2.enable.doAs","true")
  .config("hive.server2.authentication","PAM")
  .config("hive.server2.custom.authentication.class","org.apache.hive.service.auth.PamAuthenticationProvider")
  .config("hive.server2.authentication.pam.services","sshd,sudo")
  .config("hive.stats.dbclass","jdbc:mysql")
  .config("hive.stats.jdbcdriver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  .config("hive.session.history.enabled","true")
  .config("hive.metastore.schema.verification","false")
  .config("hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition","false")
  .config("hive.optimize.insert.dest.volume","false")
  .config("datanucleus.fixedDatastore","true")
  .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir","/user/hive/warehouse")
  .config("datanucleus.autoCreateSchema","false")
  .config("datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll","true")
  .config("datanucleus.schema.validateConstraints","true")
  .config("datanucleus.schema.validateColumns","true")
  .config("datanucleus.schema.validateTables","true")       
  .config("fs.default.name","hdfs://sparkserver:54310")
  .config("dfs.namenode.name.dir","/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode")
  .config("dfs.datanode.name.dir","/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
import spark.sql

sql("select * from sample.source").collect.foreach(println)
sql("select * from sample.destination").collect.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Connection request to the meta-store is been refused by remote hive server.

ERROR:Failed to start hive-metastore.service: Unit hive-metastore.service not found

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we don't need to point to remote metastore separately.

Hive-site.xml will have conf about pointing to metastore through jdbc internally.

The same conf can set as follows in program before initializing Hive-Context:

Give it a try.

```
System.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", "jdbc:mysql://<ip>/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true")
...("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
...("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName", "mysql-user")
...("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword", "mysql-passwd")
```

Comment: Raktotpal, Im having two different hive installations one is in localhost having hive.metastore.uris as <value/> its working fine when im trying to access tables from hive which is in localhost and my spark is also running in the localhost machine, but now Im trying to connect with the remote machine  having hive installed and its metstore is  thrift://sparkserver:9083

Comment: Yeahh, I understand, Use hive-site.xml then - with all those properties mentioned in my ANSWER. ------------ Program will be able to connect to that hive server. Hive-Metastore service is not running at all in that remote hive server; so, no need to connect to metastore server separatelyy.

Comment: But I dont want to use Hive-site.xml file Instead i want to call all the properties in config. I will try and let you know

Comment: Check my answer, Set those props as `System.setProperties(...)`; before instantiating SqlContext and HiveContext.

Comment: But I'm not using SqlContext or HiveContext, I'm using SparkSession directly to fetch data from hive and its working fine in localhost. I have pasted the whole code in the question.

Comment: I have used System.setProperty like you said before sparksession but same error

Comment: My metastore is not running in my remote as you said.

Comment: is there is any connection between database schema and metastore ?

Comment: As I said, Your remote hive server is not using separate metastore service for storing metadata; ------- It uses local MYSQL as metastore; that's why u need to set `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` and related porps; avod connecting metastore service

Comment: I'm using config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL","jdbc:mysql://sparkserver:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true") in my program but in remote hive server i have javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL as jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true. will it cause any issue

Comment: no issue, as localhost is fine for that remote - server to loop back, but u need to giv proper ip. thtaz correct.

Comment: Raktotpal, I have posed my whole code in the question above, please have a look and correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: And the value for hive.metastore.uris property in remote hive-site.xml is "<value/> "

Comment: thank you so much, it was my mistake I have tried without starting hive metaservice "hive --service metastore" helped me to run it

Answer (score 1):

when you use this: `.config("hive.metastore.uris", "hive2://hiveserver:9083")`, `hiveserver` should be proper remote hive server's ip.

The conf `hive.metastore.uris` points to the hive-metastore service; and if you are running locally (in localhost) - and want remote-metastore; you need to start hive-metastore service separately.

```
`$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service metastore` -p 9083
```

Or - by-default, Hive uses local Hive-metastore; so in that case, you dont need to set any value for `hive.metastore.uris`

And - forgot to mention, the property you are setting - always uses `thrift` protocol - whether hiveserver1 or hiveserver2.

So, always use this:

```
.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://hiveserver:9083")
```

Comment: I used (--service metastore` -p 9083) this command in the remote machine in hive interface, but no luck same error persist

Comment: When you start metastore service; what logs appeared in console? `hive --service metastore -p 9083`

Comment: remote machine hostname is sparkserver, so what should I give sparkserver or username@sparkserver ?

Comment: I got this in my log file SessionStart SESSION_ID="137c7345-22bf-4d5f-8af7-62761e143b04" TIME="1497525993240"

Comment: Try `ifconfig` in remote machine where metastore service is running - and give that ip in `hive.metastore.uris` as `thrift://<ip>:9083`

Comment: how to know metastore service is up and running or its status

Comment: Try this: `netstat -an|grep LIST|grep 9083`

Comment: No output blank line

Comment: That means - no metastore is running. have you started metastore service correctly??? -------- start like this as background daemon and chck:: `sudo service hive-metastore start`

Comment: Failed to start hive-metastore.service: Unit hive-metastore.service not found.

Comment: Check in your cluster where spark is running; go to hive location; check where `metastore.uris` is pointing to. --- and use that address. -------------------------------------- if no `hive.metastore.uris`, that means, hiveserver's local metastore is used. and no need for remote metastore.